# Struct protocol with variable of any (other protocol) won't conform without associatedtype

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I am trying to set up some protocols for mocking and previews, ran into and solved a conformance issue on the `Message` struct, but I could use help understanding *why* I needed an `associatedtype`.

```swift
public protocol ChatUser: Identifiable {
    var id: String { get }
    var avatar: UIImage { get }
}

public struct User: ChatUser {
    public let id: String
    public let avatar: UIImage
}

public protocol ChatMessage: Identifiable {
    var id: String { get }
    var date: Date { get }
    var text: String { get }
    var user: any ChatUser { get }
}

public struct Message: ChatMessage {
    public let id: String
    public let date: Date = Date.now
    public let text: String
    public let user: User
}
```

Xcode was telling me that `Type 'Message' does not conform to protocol 'ChatMessage'` and suggests adding `user: ChatUser` when I already have `user: User` where `User` does in fact conform to `ChatUser`.

I solved this by adding an `associatedtype` to ChatMessage:

```swift
public protocol ChatMessage: Identifiable {
    associatedtype MessageAuthor: ChatUser
    var id: String { get }
    var date: Date { get }
    var text: String { get }
    var user: MessageAuthor { get }
}
```

I'm at a loss as to why `any ChatUser` does not work here but an `associatedtype` of ChatUser does.

Comment: `public let user: any ChatUser` would also work

Comment: Yes, why not just `public let user: any ChatUser`? But I think explanation comes from the fact that your protocols inherit `Identifiable`, which has `associatedtype`. That `associatedtype` is only resovled on concrete implementation level. So by saying `any` or `associatedtype MessageAuthor: ChatUser` you allow to delay that resolution until a concrete type shows up. Try to replace `Identifiable` with some protocol that has no associatedtype, and you will see that you will be able to say `var user: ChatUser { get }`

Comment: I also think that it's better to define protocol as `public protocol ChatUser: Identifiable where ID == String` and not redefine the `id` property of the Identifiable.

Comment: Thanks both for the info and @rapiddevice great suggestion on the `where` clause. I didn't see that one. If you make it a comment I'll accept it.